# Fail to enable booking time slot in D7

Tags: 7

I am newbie to Drupal. I am trying to install booking timeslot module in D7. I've installed 7.x-1.x-dev version. However, I fail to enable the module.

The description for the booking time slots as below:

> Provides features for Booking Time Slots
>   Requires: Booking Timeslots (disabled), Addressfield (missing), Calendar (enabled), Views (enabled), Chaos tools (enabled), Date API (enabled), Date Views (enabled), Date (enabled), Entity (missing), Entityreference (missing), Features (missing), Hierarchical_select (missing), Hs_taxonomy (missing), Hs_taxonomy_views (missing), List (enabled), Field (enabled), Field SQL storage (enabled), Options (enabled), Number (enabled), Opening_hours (missing), Taxonomy (enabled), Text (enabled), Workflow (missing)

Can anyone help to tell me what to do so that I can enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules that in that list are followed by "(missing)" are the modules that are not present in the Drupal installation, and that are required from the module you are trying to install. Just install them, and you will be able to install the [Booking Time Slots](https://drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module.

The trick is understanding which modules you need. Since the modules are not found on the server, what the module page shows is not the module name, but the short name of the module capitalized.

The list of the modules that site needs is the following:

- [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity)
- [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
- [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features)
- [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)
- [Opening hours](https://drupal.org/project/opening_hours)

As you see, the module pages says that the Opening_hours module is missing, but the module name is *Opening hours*, while opening_hours is the short name of the module, the same used in the URL for the project page. Join https://drupal.org/project with opening_hours, and you get the complete URL of the project page for the module you are looking for: https://drupal.org/project/opening_hours.

The list of modules is shorter because there are modules that are sub-modules of modules already listed as requirements.

The *Opening hours* module then depends from the following modules:

- Date Popup (part of the [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) module)
- [Tipsy](https://drupal.org/project/tipsy)

Answer (score 1):

Simply download and install all the missing modules listed. So for example, download features(missing), entityreference(missing) and anything looking like that